# No syntax-highlight in c-mode *immediately* after enabling

Tags: font-lock, syntax-highlighting, c-mode

I'm writing tests for [`color-identifiers-mode`](https://github.com/ankurdave/color-identifiers-mode) I co-maintain, and I stumbled upon a problem that after creating a buffer and enabling `c-mode` in it, there is no highlight over keywords.

For example, if you open a usual C file containing `struct foo;`, executing a `(print (get-text-property (point) 'face))` over the first character will give you `font-lock-keyword-face`.

However, doing the same in a temporary buffer with `c-mode` enabled gives instead `nil`:

```lisp
(with-temp-buffer
  (insert "struct foo;")
  (c-mode)
  (goto-char 1)
  (print (get-text-property (point) 'face))) ;; evaluating will give you `nil'
```

Any ideas, how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, if you explicitly call either `(font-lock-ensure)` or `(font-lock-fontify-buffer)` *(the latter is purposed for interactive usage, byte-compilation will give you a warning about that)*, then at least in case of `c-mode` it will force fontification of the buffer. So this code works:

```lisp
(with-temp-buffer
  (insert "struct foo;")
  (c-mode)
  (goto-char 1)
  (font-lock-ensure)
  (print (get-text-property (point) 'face))) ;; evaluating will give you `font-lock-keyword-face'
```

It's worth noting that some major modes may not require that. But font-lock automates various operations, so most likely will be used.